# Matching invisible characters in JavaScript RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got some string that contain invisible characters, but they are in somewhat predictable places.  Typically the surround the piece of text I want to extract, and then after the 2nd occurrence I want to keep the rest of the text.

I can't seem to figure out how to both key off of the invisible characters, *and* exclude them from my result. To match invisibles I've been using this regex: `/\xA0\x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F/` which does seem to work.

Here's an example: `[invisibles]Keep as match 1[invisibles]Keep as match 2`

Here's what I've been using so far without success:

`/([\xA0\x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]+)(.+)([\xA0\x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]+)/(.+)`

I've got the capture groups in there, but it's bee a while since I've had to use regex's in this way, so I know I'm missing something important.  I was hoping to just make the invisible matches non-capturing groups, but it seems that JavaScript does not support this.

Comment: A non-capturing group would be `(?:something)` rather than `(something)`. Could you show also a little bit of the JS that uses that regex? Why is the closing `/` not quite at the end of your regex? (See also [MDN's regex page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).)

Comment: "invisible characters" you mean like Sue from the fantastic four? No? How about defining that a little more clearly then?

Comment: How are you actually getting the data from the match? If you are reading only the two capture groups, then it should be fine. What is that second `(.+)` outside of your second regex though?

Comment: In your case, there's no reason to use a non-capturing group--regex characters are non-capturing by default.  Just capture the ones you want.

Comment: @7stud No - invisible characters aren't a standard term. Does the questioner mean whitespace? If so he can just use '\s'

Comment: No I do not mean whitespace (spaces & tabs), I mean non-printing control characters.  Also, I know what a non-capturing group is, but it seems that JavaScript does not support them from what I've read.  Is this incorrect?

Comment: @ChrisBarr Is my not answer not working for you? JS does support non-capture groups, but without seeing some of your JS, it is hard to say what your issue is.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to try your answer out until tonight, and it works perfectly.  Thanks!  You are right about just not using capture groups, I'm not sure why I didn't try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this seems like what you want. The second regex you have pretty much works, but the `/` is in totally the wrong place. Perhaps you weren't properly reading out the group data.

```
var s = "\x0EKeep as match 1\x0EKeep as match 2";
var r = /[\xA0\x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]+(.+)[\xA0\x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]+(.+)/;

var match = s.match(r);

var part1 = match[1];
var part2 = match[2];
```

Comment: just to be clear. There are invisible characters between all characters right. So in string `"abc"` there are 3 invisible characters. like this I=specialcharacter. `IaIbIc`

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I'm not sure I 100% follow, are you asking if every string automatically has invisible characters between all the visible characters? If so, the answer is no, that is not the case. If you have a specific question, please create a new one.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer You can write a regex that can match the space between characters, but that does not mean there is an invisible character between each one.

Comment: wow that is confusing but thanks...so if get a match between `ab` what exactly i am matching with.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Please open a new question.