# Invalid characters in a txt document that force downloading instead of opening in new tab

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, gulp

I have been searching for hours on any information that can help with this problem I am having with invalid characters in a txt doc.

I have a bunch of txt files that correspond to txt versions of email where I have to get rid of invalid characters - a lot of which I assume are coming from word.

If I run "od -c filename.txt" in the command terminal these characters will be represented with "003" - but they are absolutely invisible in my txt document. I can get rid the Microsoft Word version of apostrophe's and other visible, but invalid, characters with a simple find and replace in my gulp.js file, but these characters must not be detected.

I am looking for a good method to get rid of these characters automatically with some type of gulp command, and even being able to detect them somehow would be a huge leap forward for me. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: Have you tried to detect the invalid char's with their corresponding hex code, as describe at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205646/matching-invisible-characters-in-javascript-regex)?